# Как заменить курсор в окне приложения?

Tags: winapi

Я загружаю курсор при помощи `loadCursorFromFile()`, получаю переменную типа `hCursor`. Как установить полученный курсор для окна моего приложения? В идеале, необходимо заменить несколько стандартных курсоров и потом иметь возможность переключать их при помощи стандартных идентификаторов: обычный, песочные часы и т.д.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, функция называется `LoadCursorFromFile` а не `loadCursorFromFile`. Это существенно, поскольку имена функций WinAPI чувствительны к регистру букв.

Во-вторых, эта функция возвращает результат типа `HCURSOR`, а не `hCursor`. По той же причине.

Хотя все это верно собственно для WinAPI. Ваш язык (который вы не указали) может использовать свои обертки с другими именами.

В-третьих, функция установки курсора называется [SetCursor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setcursor) (неожиданно:).

Comment: я использовал `SetCursor`, но курсор не менялся, потом понял, что (как написано по вашей ссылке) курсор сбрасывается на стандартный при каждом перемещении мыши. Есть возможность избежать необходимости устанавливать курсор в событии перемещения мыши (каждый раз при ее перемещении, нажатии и т.д.)?

Comment: @nup, не совсем так. Курсор сбрасывается при событии мыши только в том случае, если в классе соответствующего окна задан свой курсор. И сбрасывается он не на стандартный, а на классовый. Тут все логично, чего же вы ждали? А избежать этого просто - не задавайте классовый курсор. Зачем его задавать если вы его хотите постоянно заменять?

Comment: есть возможность через winApi сбросить этот классовый курсор? Видимо, он задается конструктором (язык Delphi).

Comment: @nup, посмотрите функцию [SetClassLongPtr](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setclasslongptrw), аргумент `GCLP_HCURSOR`. Еще вариант (который вам по идее в любом случае нужно сделать) - задать обработчик для `WM_MOUSEMOVE` и задавать курсор там.